# How to find the manual page for a certain systemd directive (e.g. 'WorkingDirectory')?

Tags: systemd

**systemd** does support `WorkingDirectory` entry for ***.service** units under `[Service]` section. I have examined `systemd.unit` and `systemd.service` man pages and cannot find any mentions of this property.

Question: What man page can I look into to see documentation of `WorkingDirectory` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `systemd.directives` manual page for an index of all configuration directives. `WorkingDirectory` is listed under `UNIT DIRECTIVES`:

```
   WorkingDirectory=
       systemd.exec(5)
```

so that particular directive is documented in

```
man systemd.exec
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to `systemd.directives`!